# Monitor buttons acting totally incorrectly - trying to switch input source instead of showing the OSD

Tags: button, display, monitor, hdmi

I am a bit new here, English is not my native, so I am sorry for any possible misspelling.

I have a very odd problem - my Xiaomi Mi Surface Display 34" (XMMNTWQ34 model) monitor buttons act really strange - instead of calling the monitor OSD, pressing any of 4 present buttons tries to switch to another possible input source (this is even not their function!), but no luck: just 3 seconds of the black screen and it turns back to the initial image. Let me explain how I got into this.

I have a monitor named before, which has 4 input ports: 2 DP and 2 HDMI. There is a PC always connected to the monitor via the DP interface (DP1 to be exact). Today I tried to connect a second PC via HDMI to the HDMI1 port. It went totally good, I was able to switch between PCs using a monitor OSD. But I thought it was too long and complicated to press a dozen buttons on OSD just to change an input source, so started to google any other programmatical methods of doing such thing.

Some fact: there are no drivers for this monitor on the Internet (it actually works at full 3440x1440@144 Hz resolution/refresh rate via DP interface without any trouble, but Windows sees it as "Generic PnP Monitor", so I see no way to fix it without a relevant driver).

I have found that any VESA-compatible monitor has the 0x60 parameter, which means exactly "input source", so altering the value of this parameter switches the input source without the need to call an OSD. I have found that the possible values of this 0x60 parameter for my monitor provided by several utilities are: 0x0F, 0x10, 0x11, and 0x12. But setting any of these values got me no luck - the screen just flashed black and nothing more. Moreover, those utilities showed that the current value of the 0x60 parameter was 0x07 - described as "S-Video 1" input source, and it did not change at any made tries. But my monitor does not even have such input ports!

[image: A utility output]

But I discovered a total disaster a bit later - when I tried to switch the input source via OSD, I was not able to call it - any of the 4 buttons on the monitor was causing a black flash and nothing more! So OSD is now totally unavailable! This is madness. I can't enter the OSD, I can't change the input source without turning off any one of 2 connected PCs, I can't do anything which is supposed to be made via OSD. Rebooting and reattaching of every possible thing has no effect - even with 2 PCs being connected to monitor and waiting to enter a BIOS password (no OS loaded whatsoever): pressing any button on the monitor causes only black flash and nothing more, no OSD called. I guess this is a strictly monitor firmware issue because the OSD worked well until yesterday.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this, I googled this all day long, but no luck. System restore did not change anything. Please help. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same issue when trying to change the input source using the ControlMyMonitor application on windows. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I can just chime in and say I have the same problem since today... I'll try and search for a solution but jm not too hopeful...

Answer (score 1):

Same issue after using ControlMyMonitor App. At the time being, i didn't found any solution to get the OSD back. And I didn't found any solution to factory reset the monitor, I don't know if it's possible.

I strongly discourage users to use any kind of VESA com application on this Xiaomi 34 monitor !

Now, the best solution in order to switch inputs, is to disconnect or shutdown one of the computer connected, ans it will switch automaticaly to the only one remaining. (Or use a VESA script...)